# Equivalent property `num.consumer.fetchers` for the new kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

In old consumer configs of Kafka, there is a property `num.consumer.fetchers` in order to configure the number fetcher threads used to fetch data.
In the new consumer configs of Kafka, is there any property with this same function?
And if not, how is the new consumer working on that?

Answer (score 2):

The new consumer is single-threaded (excluding the background heartbeat thread), so no equivalent config is offered.

By the way, 'num.consumer.fetchers' does not specify the number of fetcher threads as the doc says. It actually controls the possible maximum number of fetcher threads that Kafka can create.

Comment: Okay! In that case, so I can consume messages in a faster way, should I instantiate more consumers, multiple clients?

Comment: Multiple consumers in a same consumer group will be assigned with different partitions, so only adding consumer numbers does not help. You should tune the config options Kafka offers to achieve this. Actually, message consuming is often much faster than the event processing, so a lot of efforts have been made to improve the latter.